# Efficient Boundary Approximation

Tags: arrays, cell, polygon, approximation, boundary

Imagine I have the following structure represented in an array:

---

[image]

---

The blue cells represent "boundaries" and the red cell represents the structures origin. I have a function that calculates the distances of each interior cell (cells which aren't boundaries) to its closest boundary and to the origin.

Currently I do this with a nested for loop which essentially tests all cell positions to my current position and selects the cell with the smallest distance which is also marked a boundary cell.

For small data-sets this is okay, but when you have a large array of possible points to iterate through this comes painfully slow.

I am looking for a solution which would be faster but trade accuracy. Currently I am able to return the exact closest boundary cell to any given interior cell but I only really need a close approximation of which cell is closest.

Each cell in the array already has the following information:

- Arbitrary position (used for distance calculation)
- Is a Boundary Cell
- A list of neighbours (any cells which share an edge)

Things to note:

- The structure does not necessarily conform to any type of specific polygon shape
- The array isn't necessarily ordered in any logical way
- The array is flat (i.e 1D)

Possible solutions I have thought of (but have otherwise untested):

- An A* approach (as each cell knows its neighbour I could do something like this but I think it would be worse for performance than my current brute force method
- A priority queue which sorts from smallest to largest distance from origin (but unsure of how to achieve approximate closest border)

Comment: You need to explain how you define the distance between two cells.

Comment: Euclidean distance between two points in 3D space. Although I am more interested in the return of the boundary cell itself than the distance between them (as the boundary cell has properties that I need to read)

Comment: So each cell has a distinguished point, and you use those to determine distance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that the cells are irrelevant. Everything just depends on the distinguished points in the cells. Finding the distance to the origin is one calculation and cannot be improved. So your problem reduces to: You have red points and white points (to stick to your color scheme), and you want to find the closest blue point to each white point.

This is a version of [*nearest-neighbor search*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor_search). There is extensive
literature on this problem, as well as variants such as approximate nearest-neighbor search. Here is one paper that could lead you to others:

> Connor, Michael, and Piyush Kumar. "Practical Nearest Neighbor Search in the Plane." *SEA*. 2010. ([Springer link](https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/978-3-642-13193-6_42).)

The bottom line is that with appropriate data structures, you can achieve
O(log n) query time per white point, which is much faster than the naive linear search.